# matplotlib: savefig and multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

I have trouble using multiprocessing to speed up the saving of figures.
The following shortened version of code is found everywhere on stackoverflow as refered to working:

```
import multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    num_figs = 20
    input = zip(np.random.randint(10,1000,num_figs),
            range(num_figs))
    pool.map(plot, input)

def plot(args):
    num, i = args
    fig = plt.figure()
    data = np.random.randn(num).cumsum()
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.title('Plot of a %i-element brownian noise sequence' % num)
    fig.savefig('temp_fig_%02i.png' % i)

main()
```

[sample Output generated by above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9KP3.png)

For me it doesnt anyway... As one can see in the above image, the generated output has some problems with labels and titles, etc. Seems that those are not able to be pickeled.

I am using OSX running python 3

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: I think your are mistaken: `Seems that those are not able to be pickled.`. You are not pickling those, you are pickling your `data_list`. That`s the input which you don't show and which is likely causing your problem. ... Code changed ... after the fact ...

Comment: I just edited. I pasted the wrong code. This one was what i used